# Need Private Sub for Multiple Target columns

Tags: excel, vba

since i have to lock certain columns, Priate sub is not working and I need to select certain cells for the Provate sub to work, For instance: I need from column 1 to 9 and 11 to 26 and 29 to 76

```
If Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column <= 76 Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tested solution. For the sheet protection, you should allow "Format cells". The previous solution will work if you do that. Anyway, please throw it out and use this code instead. It is more clearly written.

> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
>
> ```
> Dim Cell As Range
>
> Application.EnableEvents = False
> With Target
>     If PermitModify(.Column) Then
>         Set Cell = Cells(.Row, 1)
>         If Not Cell.Locked Then
>             Cell.Value = Now
>             If .Worksheet.Protection.AllowFormattingCells Then
>                 .Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
>             End If
>         End If
>     End If
> End With
> Application.EnableEvents = True
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Function PermitModify(Clm As Long) As Boolean
>
> ```
> Dim Clms As Variant
> Dim Rng() As String
> Dim i As Integer
>
> Clms = Array("1-9", "11-26", "29-75")
> For i = 0 To UBound(Clms)
>     If Clm >= Val(Clms(i)) Then
>         Rng = Split(Clms(i), "-")
>         If UBound(Rng) = 0 Then
>             ReDim Preserve Rng(1)
>             Rng(1) = Rng(0)
>         End If
>         If Clm <= Val(Rng(1)) Then
>             PermitModify = True
>             Exit For
>         End If
>     End If
> Next i
> ```
>
> End Function

This code will first check if the cell is in a permitted column. (Same function as before but renamed in context.) Then it will check if the cell in column A is locked and will still do nothing if it is found locked.
If it is unlocked the date and time will be written into it.
Next, the code will check if your protection allows cell formatting. If it does the modified cell will be coloured. If cell formatting isn't permitted under the protection rules the cell will not be coloured, but you won't get an error either.

To make your sheet more user friendly, I suggest to disallow "Select locked cells" in the worksheet protection dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following function in the same code module where your "Private Sub" is, but after the "End Sub" of that procedure.

```
Private Function IsLocked(Clm As Long) As Boolean

    Dim Clms As Variant
    Dim Rng() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Clms = Array("1-9", "11-26", "29-75")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Clms)
        If Clm >= Val(Clms(i)) Then
            Rng = Split(Clms(i), "-")
            If UBound(Rng) = 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve Rng(1)
                Rng(1) = Rng(0)
            End If
            If Clm <= Val(Rng(1)) Then
                IsLocked = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Replace your existing line of code as posted by you above with this line.

> If Islocked(Target.Column) Then

Within the IsLocked function modify the line
Clms = Array("1-9", "11-26", "29-75")
to list the columns on which you want your code to take action (previously columns 1 - 75). You can also specify single columns, like "9" in the next example.

Clms = Array("1-6", "9", "11-26", "29-75"), as many groups as you may require.

Comment: Hi, should i paste this after End Sub?. i tried and getting error. the below is my code. Now what next to be done?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)

If Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column <= 76 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub

Comment: In your code, replace "If Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column <= 76 Then" with "If IsLocked(Target.Column) Then". Make sure that the function I gave you earlier is correctly installed as I instructed. Your code will run same as before (including any errors it might contain) but it will run on the columns determined in the function.

Comment: Can't imagine what error there might be, unless you installed the function inside your sub instead of after it. The entire function, including its declaration and End Function lines, must be pasted below the "End Sub" line of your existing sub.

Comment: This is how i tried and still getting error, pls correct me if wrong

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)

If IsLocked(Target.Column) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

Comment: Private Function IsLocked(Clm As Long) As Boolean

    Dim Clms As Variant
    Dim Rng() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Clms = Array("1-9", "11-26", "29-75")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Clms)
        If Clm >= Val(Clms(i)) Then
            Rng = Split(Clms(i), "-")
            If UBound(Rng) = 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve Rng(1)
                Rng(1) = Rng(0)
            End If
            If Clm <= Val(Rng(1)) Then
                IsLocked = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Comment: Thanks a ton, this works but am not getting color highlighted in modified cells

Comment: This may be because of how you set the worksheet protection. In the protection dialog box you must check the box for "Format cells". It is the 3rd checkbox from the top. The code also checks if the cell in column A, where you write the time, is unlocked. It will not write the time if the cell is locked even if protection is disabled and also not highlight the modified cell. This behaviour is different with and without protection set.

Comment: Bingo, it works.... Thanks!